# Run android open source code in emulator.SD card error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I downloaded the source code of the [ringdroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) android application. I need to run this application on the android emulator through eclipse ADT plugin.

But it gives the following error when I try to execute the application on the emulator. The error is displayed on emulator when project is loaded. The error is

> add SD card before running application

Help me with this as i need to have execute able code for my project.

Comment: Just create an AVD with an SD card.  Google will show you how.

Comment: that also not working..i tried

Comment: why we need SD card ? and where it is displayed in window

Comment: I assume that in the manifest, the app has requested to be installed on the SD card. "and where it is displayed in window "  Where is what displayed in window?

Answer (score 1):

click on Window->AVD Manager->selec your emulator->edit and  there is SDcard size option.
 Here fill the size of Sd card. This will make your emulator having your specified size SD card.